# Python if x is not None statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
level = '(Something '
level = re.sub(r'[()]', '', str(level).lower()) if level is not None else None
```

How can I code this properly?

If I dont include the "else None" part it raises an error. I want to apply second line only if `level` is `not None`, otherwise ignore it. Is there a way of ignoring the operation in case level is None, using only 1 Python line?

Comment: How can `level` be `None` if you set it to `'(Something '` in the line above?

Comment: Your question needs to be more explain and formatted to get a answer which best suits you. [***How do I ask a good question? - Help Center - Stack Overflow***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks for the input. level is sometimes considered as 'none', instead of None, that is why I included that else condition. Apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to exclude the 'else' in a one line conditional however one workaround would be the following:

```python
level = '(Something '
level = re.sub(r'[()]', '', str(level).lower()) if level is not None else level
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```py
level = '(Something '
if level is not None:
    level += re.sub(r'[()]', '', str(level).lower())
```

Comment: That's not "using only 1 Python line", as uk_butterfly asked for, but for an actual 1-liner, you can move the single statement in the `if` body right after the colon of the `if` statement.

Comment: @jjramsey. OT first asks "How can I code this properly?" and then asks for a 1-liner. I suggest this one since it's better with clear code than compact code.

Answer (score 0):

*If I dont include the "else None" part it raises an error.*

Indeed, you have used ternary operator which is ternary.

*Is there a way of ignoring the operation in case level is None, using only 1 Python line?*

You can use normal `if` without return after `:`, consider following simple example

```
x = 0
if x>0: x=10
print(x)
```

which output `0` as is, `10` if you change `x` to `1`. Important: before usage consult your organization's standing coding style requirements to see if such code is compliant with them.

Answer (score 0):

What about turning it from two lines into one line, like this:

```
level = re.sub(r'[()]', '', str(level).lower()) if level is not None else '(Something '
```

I don't know how can `level` be `None` when you assign `'(Something '` to it in the first line (as someone already pointed out in the comments). But if you merge those two lines into one, then there is a chance that `level` could be `None`. Hence, the logic is a little bit different than what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `re` is, but your `else` statement is redundant. Try the following:

```
level = '(Something ' 
level += re.sub(r"[()]", "", str(level).lower()) if not level is None
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this ? This is much common

```py
level = '(Something ' # Create variable
if level is not None: # If statement
    level += re.sub(r'[()]', '', str(level).lower()) # Execute the command needed
```